# Aweber Custom Template Coding

Tags: html, html-email, newsletter, aweber

i am expert  email coder  and know very well how to code email templates , now i have to code `Aweber templates`  i have been Doing  `mailchimp` ,but unfortunately i am unable to understand it ,
I went through  [This Tutorial](https://labs.aweber.com/docs/theme-language)  but  still i am confused ,  Can anyone please refer me some `tutorial or some guidance`   . i have coded email pc just have to convert to Aweber , please help

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on creating your own Aweber email templates follow below links:

```
https://labs.aweber.com/docs/creating-your-template
http://www.ehow.com/how_8403183_use-custom-html-template-aweber.html
```

You should be fine if you know html and css.

Comment: this official link  is not clear and ehow is old one , Aweber has changed  its coding style

Comment: What information is unclear?  You just create a template using html and css.  Can you provide us what part of information is unclear to you so we can try to help you with that part?

Comment: here  https://labs.aweber.com/docs/drag-n-drop-elements in this link i am not sure , if  i should add complete html in this section or what to do . although its pertty well mentioned but still not getting that  .

Comment: Drop down element are optional.  If you are confused, remove them and all them later once your template if fully functional. "Using drag and drop elements (articles, coupons, etc.) is the core of using the AWeber message editor. While your template will certainly work without customizing these elements, using them provides a safer environment for your clients to rearrange, add and delete their own content without breaking their template or branding."